# Panel data question

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I am using a difference-in-difference strategy using panel data.

I define my treatment group as mothers whose youngest child is less than 1 years old and my control group as mothers whose youngest child is between 4 and 10 years old.

I have noticed that because of the way my treatment group is defined, it consists of different women across the years.

On the other hand, my control group consists of more or less of the same women because I allow for a wider range of ages of children.

I am trying to consider what these imply for the way I use my data.

Does this imply that I cannot use the xtreg command on stata? Can I still use my data longitudinally?

Comment: Hi Mary. So individuals (women) can move out of the treatment group as they move through time? How long do you observe each woman in the panel?

Comment: Hello Tom. They move out of the treatment group as soon as their youngest child turns one as my treatment group is restricted to the women whose youngest child is below the age of one. I guess because of the way I define my treatment group I cannot use my data set longitudinally can I?

Comment: What is your treatment/policy/intervention in this case? Also, are you observing women *across years*?